# Should instance/config.py be uploaded to the production server when deploying a Flask app?

Tags: nginx, flask, uwsgi

I'm preparing to deploy a small Flask app that I've developed for internal use. I have an old laptop with Ubuntu Server 16.04, uWSGI and Nginx which I'll use for deployment.

**OPTION 1**

My current app setup has an `instance/config.py` file that I've kept **out** of version control. This file contains the following:

```
SECRET_KEY = ...
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = ...

# Google 'client_id' and 'client_secret' for social authentication functionality.
```

The `instance/config.py` file is loaded as follows in `app/__init__.py`:

```
def create_app(config_name):
  app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=true)
  app.config.from_object(app_config[config_name])
  app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
```

**Is it safe to keep this same setup for production and thus have the `instance/config.py` file in the production server?**

**OPTION 2**

Alternatively, should I be using environment variables? If this were the case, should I do something like so in `wsgi.py`:

```
os.environ['FLASK_CONFIG'] = 'production'
os.environ['SECRET_KEY'] = ...
os.environ['SQL_ALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = ...
```

and then have the following in `app/__init__.py`:

```
def create_app(config_name):
  if os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG') == 'production':
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.update(
      SECRET_KEY=os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')
      SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI=os.getenv('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI')
    )
  else:  
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=true)
    app.config.from_object(app_config[config_name])
    app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question, yes it's safe as long as your server is secure. Hopefully access is only allowed using a private key. If you're using a password to login, then that may be a problem.

It's a good idea to keep the actual file used to load configuration out of version control. I actually made a mistake with one of my servers where I did put `config.py` in version control and now I have to be careful each time I pull not overwrite the file.

One thing that you could do is to have a config file for each environment, say `prod.py` and `dev.py`, that are both checked in. Then create a `pointer.py` that is not checked into version control.

**prod.py**

```
SECRET_KEY = ...
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = ...
...
```

**pointer.py**

```
from prod import SECRET_KEY, SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, ...
```

**server.py**

```
app.config.from_pyfile('pointer.py')
```

In dev, simply change the import statement to point to `dev.py`. You could  also do `from prod import *`, but that [isn't very good practice](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports).